# Disk space rapidly decreased because /var/log/cups/error_log has become huge

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, diskspace, error-log

After I updated my Ubuntu to 12.04， my system went slow and it warned me that my disk has less space left. I checked my disk and found the file **/var/log/cups/error_log** 's size was **78G!!**.  I checked this file and found it full of "notifier for subscription dbus:// went away retrying retrying".........
What's going on here? And what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

try remove this folder and make it again with this command

sudo rm -vfr /var/log && sudo mkdir /var/log

and check if any tools make report about your system like apport disable it from here

[apport disable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

and something like this uncheck it and make record activity inactive like this in privacy option

[image: privacy option]

and in software sources uncheck this option you can this windows by type in terminal

gksu software-properties-gtk

and do that

[image]

Comment: Thanks！But I can't open those two window, when I click the privacy button in SystemSetting panel it just disappeared. And when I type the command "gksu software-properties-gtk", there will come out a icon like settings in the left unity for a few seconds and then disappear too!  Is there some authority that I haven't got?

Comment: this strange ur distro unstable I don't know check if you update your distro to latest version ubuntu 12.04.2 and your program to latest version and your kernel too by this commands copy it without quots "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo reboot" after do that and reboot try to open same window that disapper but with normal user I mean not from terminal

by the window in first photo bring it from settings and number too bring it from software sources and can bring it when open ubuntu software center and from menu above

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command below to show all the files in your drive over 1G in size

```
sudo find / -size +1G
```

You can now delete the files that you do not need.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is stop the cups server so it stops filling up your file system with errors. Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo stop cups
```

Then delete the error_log file. If you are deleting it through the gui make sure you delete it using shift + delete so it doesn't go to your trash. You might need to restart your system after. I just had this problem. Will extend this answer when I figure out a permanent solution.

#### Update #1

Stopping cups server, deleting the error_log file and rebooting solved the problem for me. cups (Common Unix Printing System) is used to connect network printers to your your machine so if you are getting lots of cups errors it is most like due to a failed printer connection or some other printer error.